# Which directory does the Visual Studio WPF Designer use from?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my simple WPF app, I'm trying to get data from a database. When I build and run the application it reads from the database correctly, but in the designer I get the error

> SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

Since this occurs the DataContext 'breaks' somehow and the rest of the DataBinding coming from that file does not 'bind' which messes up the rest of the design.

Here is the code where the database is accessed.

```
public static string ReturnNoteTitle()
{
    using var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=notesDB.db");
    //var connection = ConnectDB();
    connection.Open();            
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT noteContents FROM userNotes WHERE noteUsername = 'xx'";
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    string title = "";
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        title = reader.GetString(0);
    }
    connection.Close();           
    
    return title;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The designer copies the output in another folder so it isn't locked and prevents recompiling. However it does not copy other files there so
you need an absolute path of the project and prepend it. You can get with

```
public static string GetProjectLocation(
#if DEBUG   // use this compiler switch to prevent shipping internal paths to our customers
   [CallerFilePath]
#endif
    string sourceFilePath = "")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceFilePath))
       throw new InvalidOperationException("Use DEBUG mode for XAML deginer!");
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to use Path.GetFullPath(sourceFilePath)? Also, what do you mean by 'Use DEBUG mode for XAML Designer'? https://i.imgur.com/IiuR2Hc.png is what my tool bar looks like, is this what you are talking about?

Comment: `sourceFilePath` is already a full path. This method gets the path of the project where the disigner data resides. This method uses DEBUG compiler flag to not leak the path in release so it won't work in release mode. The exceptiopn is to have a good error message why the designer won't get data when you switch to release mode in visual studio.